# Error trapping scp exit code not working

Tags: linux, bash, scp

I have

```
# Transfer today's CMS backup to a remote backup server
scp -P 55 -r $localdumpdirectory/dirdump-cms-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz root@someserver:/$remotedumpdirectory/ >/dev/null 2>&1
status=${$}
if [[ ${status} != 0 ]]
then
    echo "Failed to secure copy directory, with code: ${status}" 
    exit 1
fi;
```

Everything is working except that even though the SCP succeeds, I get:

> Failed to secure copy directory, with code: 27348

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit code is `$?`, not `$$`. `$$` is process ID.

```
status=${$}
```

should be

```
status=$?    # or ${?} if you really insist.
```

If this is bash, see the section ["Special Parameters"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want

```
status=$?
```

That will give you the status of the last command.

```
status=$$
```

This is giving you the last PID

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PROCCID

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can shorten what you have to:

```
if scp -P 55 -r $localdumpdirectory/dirdump-cms-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz root@someserver:/$remotedumpdirectory/ >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    echo "Failed to secure copy directory, with code: ${status}" 
    exit 1
fi
```